# How to control table size entirely through html and CSS?

Tags: html, css, forms, visual-studio, visual-web-developer

I'm new to web developing and I am stuck in a task that I'll have to make a table inside of a form, however, I'm facing difficulties placing 3 text boxes next to each other with words like "country code, City code and phone number" above it in the same section.
I am using  for the table and  for each input and label.

**Your Phone**

Country code - **City code -** **Phone number**

Answer (score 0):

u can use colspan or rowspan in your table

example:

```
<table>
 <tr>
   <th colspan="3">Your Phone</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td>Country code</td>
   <td>City code</td>
   <td>Phone number</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

view more at [w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_table_colspan_rowspan.asp)